# Change the default "category" of a new case in FogBugz

Tags: fogbugz

In our FB configuration a new case is category = "Bug" per default. I would like to change that to "Inquiry". How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use FogBugz 7.0 you can customize categories through Admin --> Workflow if you have the [Custom Workflow](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/70/topics/plugins/CustomWorkflow.html) plugin installed (it is installed on default I assume). Here you can set the default category for new cases.